# Android App. Simple Calculator Crashing

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development and I ran into a snag on my first real attempt and an app.  I'm trying to make a simple calculator.  However when I run the app and enter my the second number in the sequence to be added the calculator the emulator says "Unfortunately the calculator has stopped working."  I looked at the logCat and there are a tun of red errors so I don't think I'll post all of them.

My code is as fallows:

```
    package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;


public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    EditText helloName;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    int value = 0;
    int acuum = 0;
    boolean newValue = false;

    Button add, sub, mult, div, equ, one, two, three;
    TextView display;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sub);
        mult= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Mult);
        div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Div);
        equ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Equ);   
        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.One); 
        two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Two); 
        three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Three); 
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Value);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                value = Integer.parseInt(display.getText().toString());
                acuum += value;
                newValue = true;
            }
        });

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                value = Integer.parseInt(display.getText().toString());
                acuum -= value;
                newValue = true;

            }
        });

        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(newValue == true)
                    display.setText('1');
                else
                    display.setText(display.getText().toString() +  '1');

                newValue = false;

            }
        });

        two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(newValue == true)
                    display.setText('2');
                else
                    display.setText(display.getText().toString() +  '2');

                newValue = false;

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Just to try and further clarify.  If I were to enter 1 + 2, when I click the 2 is when the app crashes. I feel like its a simple mistake that I'm just over looking.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank in advance!

LogCat Value:

05-15 02:39:30.047: D/gralloc_goldfish(540): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-15 02:39:30.097: I/dalvikvm(540): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-15 02:39:30.128: I/dalvikvm(540): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-15 02:39:46.427: W/ResourceType(540): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000032
05-15 02:39:46.427: D/AndroidRuntime(540): Shutting down VM
05-15 02:39:46.427: W/dalvikvm(540): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x32
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3473)
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroidActivity$4.onClick(HelloAndroidActivity.java:80)
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 02:39:47.077: I/dalvikvm(540): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-15 02:39:47.097: I/dalvikvm(540): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

Sorry about the formatting of the logCat.

Comment: "so I don't think I'll post all of them" - you may want to post at least a few. While Raymond Chen has psychic debugging down to a fine art, not everyone is so well equipped :-) And some information is usually better than none.

Comment: And: `acuum` seems incongruous to me, an accumulator would be called `accum` (though irrelevant to your problem). But two other possibilities, adding a string and a char (like `'2'`) - is that kosher (too tired to look it up at the moment)? And, I suspect `newValue` should be initialised to `true` rather than `false` (also  too tired to see if the display defaults to an empty string).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
I'll throw a few errors up:

Comment: I don't think adding the string is the issue as there is only a problem when I attempt to enter the second number.  I changed it to adding a string to string (by doing "2" instead of '2') and I still had the same issue.  I read that having too much in the onCreate method can cause issues, however I'm unsure how else to set up my buttons.  Also as far as acuum goes, I'm just retarded at spelling.

Comment: Fixed it!  In my display.setText('2') line the '2' needed to be "2".  Thanks for your help guys very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you may want to look at.

You use the character `'2'` in a few places where it might make more sense to use the string `"2"`. For example:

```
display.setText('1');
```

and:

```
display.setText(display.getText().toString() +  '2');
```

I think it's that first one causing your specific problem. The support for this lies in the following error from your error log:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main 05-15 02:39:46.437: E/AndroidRuntime(540):
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
>   String resource ID #0x32

`#0x32` (hex 32) is the integral value of `'2'`. If you look at the [`TextView` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), you'll see a few prototypes for `setText`, the first which takes an integral resource ID:

> public final void setText (int resid)

which explains what's happening. The `'2'` is being treated as an integer and used to look up a resource (which doesn't exist).

---

It might also be a good idea to initialise `newValue` to true rather than false, since that should be the initial state. Otherwise, if your calculator starts with "0" in the display, pressing the `1` button would give you `01` rather than `1`.

Comment: This is spot on about everything.  Thanks for the help!